# Android - Notification Reminder - Remind user to open the unread notification

Tags: android

I searched quite a bit on here and can't figure this one out. All the posted questions refer to setting a notification to go off at a certain date/time or on a schedule. This is not what I am trying to do. It might not be possible and might be a system-controlled thing.

The feature I want to emulate/override/extend/whatever is the `Notification Reminder` in Android. This feature is part of android and can be set to something like "2 min", "10 min", whatever, and if you don't check the notification from an app then the device will give a little notification sound again to remind you that you still have the notification waiting in your notification bar. Do you know the feature I am referring to? (On my S6 I go to 'Accessibility --> Notification Reminder')

Is there a way for me to create this behavior in my app without relying on the system settings?

***I want to make the device remind the user every 30 seconds that they have an unread notification from my app, and only from my app.*** The 2-minute reminder that Android offers is not enough (and also, it isn't working reliably for my users... can't figure out why. Sometimes it reminds, sometimes it doesn't.)

**ALLOW ME BE COMPLETELY CLEAR ABOUT SOMETHING:**

This app is being created for a government agency and is not being made to 'please the user'. I understand that there are certain things that are considered wrong, but trust me, that doesn't apply here. This app is for emergency notification for an 'on-call-24/7' unit with devices that are owned by the government. For example, I have a feature that allows the alert sender to force the recipient's ringtone on full blast with a preset tone. Obviously this would be terrible in a public app, but here, it is a requirement.

Thank you very much for any help! If you need me to post code, or more information about my specific implementation of the notification builder then let me know.

**UPDATE:**

Did my question get lost in the ether? lol, any takers?

Comment: This question is a little bit broad for Stack Overflow. You could implement it by checking for your notification in the notification list, and if it is there still, then play your sound.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I suppose I can re-write the question to be more specific. I think the requirement I have is not broad, but perhaps I was too winded in my question. The part that is in bold and italics is really the only thing I want to know. I am not trying to get a list of ways to achieve what I want, the question is more "can I override this default android feature".

Comment: I don't think it is possible to override the amount of time it takes for the notification alert to make noise. You will have to implement that in your app yourself.

Comment: Roger that. Thank you for your time! I was afraid it wouldn't be possible :-(  It seems like it would be a system-only type of thing.